# Two models in one Django DetailView and filtering by relation betwen them

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-generic-views

I have a question. In my `DetailView` I want to placed data from two models. Moreover, I want to filter them, that on my `scenario-detail` was only that comments related to specyfic scenario, related by ForeignKey->Scenario.

My `views.py`:

```
class ScenarioDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Scenario

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.all()
        return context
```

And in `scenario_detail.html` i have a simple `{{ comments }}`

I thinking on filtering my comment object in `views.py`, something like: `Comment.objects.get(commentScenario=Scenario.id)` but it didn't work at all.

My `models.py`:

```
class Scenario(models.Model):
    scenarioTitle = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    scenarioArea = models.ForeignKey(ScenarioArea, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    scenarioAuthor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    scenarioDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    scenarioDescription = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.scenarioTitle

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('scenario-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Comment(models.Model):
    commentText = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    commentScenario = models.ForeignKey(Scenario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    commentAuthor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    commentDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.commentText
```

And `urls.py`:

```
path('scenario/<int:pk>/', ScenarioDetailView.as_view(), name='scenario-detail'),
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to send any *extra* context to your template in order to show the **related comments**; As you *already* have the **related** comments to your `Scenario` with **backward relationship**.

So you can simply use `Scenario.comment_set.all` in your template to access them.

As an example:

```
{% for comment in object.comment_set.all %}
  {{ comment }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
class ScenarioDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Scenario

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(commentScenario=self.object)
        return context
```